# How to sort an arraylist based on column?

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to sort an Arraylist based on column.

Example:

input:--

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa

5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

output:--

With respect to Ist column

```
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

With respect to 2nd column

```
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa

5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

similarly up to second last column

Comment: An ArrayList does not have columns, only elements... Can you show some code?

Comment: Is it an ArrayList of ArrayList of Elements?

Comment: Columns means,we can separate it by tokenizer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely will have to write a custom sort. Look into [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Something along the lines of:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<List<MyObject> {
    int columnToSortOn;
    public MyComparator(int columnToSortOn) {
        this.columnToSortOn = columnToSortOn;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(List<MyObject> list1, List<MyObject> list2) {
        return list1.get(columnToSortOn).compareTo(list2.get(columnToSortOn));
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to give an answer, you should preferably also give a short code sample to illustrate how to do this. Simply pointing to the Java docs isn't really sufficient. (Not that I think this question should be given an answer at all)

Comment: Hence nudging the OP in the right direction instead of doing all the work for them. =0p

Comment: Ok, then. There's a basic example that doesn't give everything away.

Answer (score 1):

you can look at the java.util.Comparator interface and its use in java.util.Collections.sort(List, Comparator)
This allows you to define an absolute ordering on you objects.

for reference you can look into this link: http://www.coderanch.com/t/370133/java/java/Sort-Multiple-Columns